# Getting Jmeter error: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Response data i am getting: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

[image: Getting error as shown below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause of the error, Path was not given correctly in my sample pages. After giving the Path correctly, error was gone.

Thanks all spending time on this.

Update:  The path was incorrect for the following Http request pages, so after changing the path, it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

As per [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

So you need to check your application log for the error details.

A good idea would be capturing the requests which is sent by the real browser and JMeter using a sniffer tool like [Burp Proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and compare the requests which need to be the same (apart form dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

I don't like your [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) which is added as the child of the `Login Page` request, HTTP Cookie Manager obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so it should be enough to have one HTTP Cookie Manager at the Test Plan root, this way the cookies from `Zoom Page` will be available for the `Login Page` request and in your setup they are not.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. I am not getting how to pass the session ids if cookie manager placed in Test plan level. Session ids are dynamic so i put in login page. Please suggest more.